# OnQuickLaunch property in ListAdded

Tags: 2010, event-handlers

For an event receiver, I want to execute some custom code when a list is added to my site. I want to use the OnQuickLaunch property of the list, but that doesn't seem to correspond to the "show on quicklaunch" checkbox when adding a new list?

When I add a new list and set the checkbox to true; the property still reads false in ListAdded. Is it possible to read this checkbox from ListAdded?

Answer (score 2):

```
var navNode = new SPNavigationNode( yourList.Title, yourList.DefaultViewUrl);
SPContext.Current.Web.Navigation.AddToQuickLaunch(navNode, SPQuickLaunchHeading.Documents);
```

Will add your node to Documents section in quicklaunch.

`yourList.OnQuickLaunch = true` should also work as long as you remember to `list.Update()` afterwards.

Comment: I know that, but I don't want to add the list to the navigation since SharePoint can do that perfectly. But I do want to know if the new list is going to be on the Quicklaunch, depending on if the user checked the checkbox or not. SPWeb.OnQuickLaunch always returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Just did a quick test now with this code:

```
    private Guid _newlistguid;

    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        var w = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
        _newlistguid = w.Lists.Add("TestList", "Some description", SPListTemplateType.Tasks);
        var newList = w.Lists[_newlistguid];
        newList.OnQuickLaunch = true;
        newList.Update();

        //Load list again to check value of OnQuickLaunch Param
        var reloadedList = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[_newlistguid];
        var onQuickLauch = reloadedList.OnQuickLaunch;
    }
```

The onQuickLaunch parameter on the last codeline contains **true** after code has executed, so it should give you the correct value. Again, remember to call .Update() on your list after you set the list.OnQuickLaunch value.

**Update 12.01:**

I had no problems using ListAdded either:

```
public override void ListAdded(SPListEventProperties properties)
{  
    var l = properties.List;  
    _newlistguid = l.ID;  
    l.OnQuickLaunch = true;  
    l.Update();  

    var w = l.ParentWeb;  
    //Load list again to check value of OnQuickLaunch Param  
     var reloadedList = w.Lists[_newlistguid];  
     var onQuickLauch = reloadedList.OnQuickLaunch;  
}
```

onQuickLaunch contains correct value (true).
If you still can't get it to work, please provide code sample of what you are doing.

Comment: But this code is based on a feature receiver, I don't have any problems there. Try the same in a listreceiver and use the ListAdded event. I find it impossible to get the correct status there.